# Reverse Engineering a View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was asked how to reverse engineer a view so it can be determined what columns and table were used in the sql query to produce the view . So say view 1 was constructed from the following 10 tables and 43 columns . Is this even possible in sql server 2005 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [sp_helptext](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms176112.aspx)

```
exec sp_helptext 'your_view'
```

**Edit**

What you want is to find out what dependencies your view has. You can use [sp_depends](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189487.aspx) to do that, but it will only get you the table dependencies and not the columns.

```
exec sp_depends 'your_view'
```

In order to find out the columns you will probably have to code some kind of SQL parser to extract the columns being used from the Create View statement you recovered with sp_helptext.

You can try using a ReGex to extract the info you want or if you want a big and fancier gun you can try [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) which has a built in Sql Lexic.

Comment: Yeah, see the "view" in the description?

Comment: yes pff :) missed it, sorry I am used to using it for Stored Procedures :]

Comment: Thank you for replying. I aware of this . But I looking for some sql to strip out the tables and columns in the create view statement . These are view with thousands of lines of code and CTEs.

Comment: @JamesKhan updated the answer with more info about what you want

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in SSMS choose your `database` -> `views` -> right click -> `script as CREATE`.

If you want to decode a view on another database, you have no access to (e.g interface) - than this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I aware of this . But I looking for some sql to strip out the tables and columns in the create view statement . These are view with thousands of lines of code and CTEs.